# SVN error message: "E200030: sqlite: database disk image is malformed" on checkout

Tags: linux, debian, subversion, sqlite

The `.svn` folder doesn't exist yet. I tried deleting it after it was created, but I get the same issue again

```
@:/var/www/htdocs$ svn checkout https://host/svn/trunk/ .
svn: E200030: sqlite: database disk image is malformed
svn: E200030: sqlite: database disk image is malformed


@:/home/pi# svn --version
svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)
   compiled Jun 27 2012, 11:28:48

@:/home/pi# ldd /usr/bin/svn
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x404f2000)
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Does this thread contain anything that might help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007024/cygwin-svn-e200030-sqlite-disk-i-o-error

Comment: Probably it does as other voted on it. But I don't know what to do with it, as I am in lack of commands.

Comment: There is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675615/svn-cleanup-sqlite-database-disk-image-is-malformed . What is your platform? Is svn from a binary package or self-compiled? What repository are you trying to check out from?

Comment: How to see the repository I am trying to check out from?

Comment: You can list the content of the repository this way `svn ls REPO` or look at the logs like this: `svn log REPO`

Comment: I wrote the accepted answer referred to in the first comment, so I can say "no, that isn't the same problem." Not in anything but the broadest sense anyway. I don't see how you get this error at all without an `.svn` directory, since that means you also lack `.svn/wc.db`. What happens if you say `mkdir foo ; cd foo ; svn co https://host/svn/trunk` instead? (Yes, four changes here, all on purpose.) Also, is your platform really running on ARM? Can you do this same checkout on a different platform?

Comment: It's possible that svn client is finding a .svn directory in some upper-level dir... not sure if this feature can be disabled.